# Materials for learning about patent litigation and valuation?

Tags: litigation, book, blogs, valuation, learning

I'm an engineer with a fair bit of business and strategy experience. I also read several books about patents, large parts of the Manual of Patent Examination Procedure (MPEP), many patent documents, and worked with attorneys to co-author patent applications. That all is to say that I have some background with patents but I don't have formal Law School training.

I recognize that an area I need to learn more about is patent litigation and valuation/strength estimation. I want to get better at estimating which parts of a patent will stand up to challenge, which may fold, and what common arguments are brought forth when one is dealing with a gray area or a matter of interpretation (as is so often the case). Also, I'd like to get a sense of how all that plays out differently across different geographies (e.g. US, Germany, Japan).

Can you recommend books, blogs, and other materials to help me study? I'm thinking that concrete examples akin to case studies used in Business Schools could be particularly helpful. Online courses could also be helpful.

Comment: Follow PatentlyO

Answer (score 1):

“Understanding Global patent litigations through landmark judgements – A litigation ready reckoner” by Dr. Alpesh Pathak is only book i am aware of my be this would be helpful for understanding the basics as it deals mostly with litigation's in perspective of pharmaceuticals.